# How To Convert Format Number to Number

Tags: javascript, html

I use javascript format number as: 1,000,000 but i can't use operators +, -, *, / with number in "BOX INPUT".

and then click try it:

Error below:

> SO TIEN GOC:NaN
>   SO TIEN GOC:NaN

This is my code:

[My Code Link Error](https://jsfiddle.net/zku1ko28/)

```
result = split[1] != undefined ? result + decimal_separator + split[1] : result; 
parseInt('result'); 
return prefix == undefined ? result : (result ? prefix + result : '');
```

Thank You !

Comment: Cause `+-*/` arent part of a number??

Comment: what is a single `parseInt('result');` doing?

Comment: please add what to input and when you get the error. the given code should work.

Comment: `parseInt('result');` isn't correct, you might have better luck with `parseInt(result);`, (without quotes)

Comment: I try parseInt(result); it's not correct.  When Click Function "TRY IT"  Error number NaN. My function: function myFunction() { 
var x = document.getElementById("ST").value;
var y = document.getElementById("TG").value; 
var sotien = x/y;
var i;
var text = "";
for (i = 0; i < y; i++) {
text += "SO TIEN GOC:" + sotien + "<br>";
}
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}

Answer (score 0):

I did it by replacing global variable "," to "" and then it's converted to Number.

```
var  x = document.getElementById("ST").value.replace(/,/g,"");
var  y = document.getElementById("TG").value.replace(/,/g,"");
```